# Sum of positive two-digit numbers containing 3

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find the sum of all positive two-digit numbers containing the digit 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to find the sum of all positive two-digit numbers containing the digit $d\not=0$ evaluate 
$$S_d:=\sum_{k=0}^9\left(10\cdot d+k\right)+\sum_{k=1}^9\left(10\cdot k+d\right)-11\cdot d.$$
The first sum is the sum of all positive two-digit numbers containing the digit d as the first digit. The second sum is the sum of all positive two-digit numbers containing the digit d as the second digit. The number $d\cdot 11$ is subtracted because it has been counted two times.
Hence
\begin{align*}
S_d&= 100\cdot d+\sum_{k=1}^9k +10\sum_{k=1}^9k+9\cdot d- 11\cdot d\\
&=
98\cdot d+11\sum_{k=1}^9k=98\cdot d+11\cdot \frac{9\cdot 10}{2}=98\cdot d +495.
\end{align*}
For $d=3$ we obtain $S_3=789$.

Comment: @Lozenges Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: The computer says that the sum of all numbers in $[0, 99]$ containing the digit $d$ is $495 + 99 \times d$. This generalizes this result.

Comment: @Gribouillis OP asks for two digits numbers so one $d$ should be subtracted from your result.

Comment: I know, but I prefer to count first without this unnatural condition. For 1, 2 or 3 digits, the numerical result is $94905 + 8991\times d$. Some further generalization is still possible (I count $3 = 003$) as containing $0$ here.

Comment: Your formula fails with $d=0$. Indeed the sum of two digits numbers containing zero is $450$ and not $495$. Maybe you count $09, 08, 07$ etc in your computation... which add to $45$, the exceeding quantity